# To use closures or not, John Conways Game of Life

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, closures, conways-game-of-life

I am currently making a game that illustrates [John Conways 'Game of Life'](https://bitstorm.org/gameoflife/)
I've been learning about closures and the modular patterns and am trying to implement more of what I'm learning in Javascript. [You can check out my repo here if your interested.](https://github.com/mrslwiseman/fcc-game-of-life) All of these methods are inside a 'Game' object. I have it working, but am trying to limit variables and make it as functional as possible (passing the grid array between functions). I would like some advice on wether I should be keeping higher scope variable immutable or wether it doesnt matter.

**Which solution is better practise, in terms of structure?**

```
// initial grid
// will be bigger than this but is 3x3 for this question.

let grid = [
    [1,0,0],
    [0,1,0],
    [0,0,1]
]
```

**Solution 1:** My initial way of solving:

```
function nextGrid(){
  grid = applyRules(grid)
  renderGrid(grid)
}

function applyRules(grid){
  // makes changes
}

function renderGrid(grid){
  // makes changes
}

// call nextGrid() to generate subsequent new grids.
```

**Solution 2:** Having looked into closures more, is this better?

```
function nextGrid() {
  let prevGrid = grid;

  return function(){
    prevGrid = applyRules(prevGrid)
    renderGrid(prevGrid)
  }  
}

function applyRules(prevGrid){
  // makes changes
}

function renderGrid(grid){
  // makes changes
}

const next = nextGrid();

// call next() to generate subsequent new grids.
```

Comment: @Bergi thanks for point that out. this is just pseudo code that i wrote out to demonstrate my question anyway.

Comment: Your second solution has the advantage of being able to create multiple independent games by calling `nextGrid()` multiple times. If you don't need that, don't use it - you could e.g. simplify it to an IIFE that creates `next` directly. Then it still has the advantage of mutating `prevGrid` instead of the initial `grid` - again, that's good if you need it (keep the initial grid around for something) but overcomplicated if not.

Comment: IIFE idea works a treat. Thanks for helping me on my learning journey!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both your solutions employ mutation. In your first solution you mutate the global variable `grid`. In your second solution you mutate the local variable `prevGrid`. A truly functional program would use recursion instead of mutation. For example, this is what I'd do:

```js
const game = /* initial game state */;

play(game);

function play(game) {
    render(game);
    setTimeout(play, 100, update(game));
}
```

As you can see, instead of mutating the global variable `game` we call `play` with an updated game state every 100 milliseconds. Our initial call `play(game)` on the third line starts the game. If we comment it out, nothing will be displayed.

---

Here's a complete example of [Conway's Game of Life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life) in a few lines of code:

```js
const glyph = [" ", "■"];

document.querySelectorAll("pre.life").forEach(e => play(e, read(e.innerHTML)));

function read(text) {
    return text.split("\n").map(l => l.split("").map(c => glyph.indexOf(c)));
}

function play(pre, game) {
    pre.innerHTML = show(game);
    setTimeout(play, 100, pre, update(game));
}

function show(game) {
    return game.map(line => line.map(cell => glyph[cell]).join("")).join("\n");
}

function update(game) {
    return game.map((line, i) => line.map((cell, j) => {
        const back = game[i - 1], next = game[i + 1], h = j - 1, k = j + 1;

        const neighbors = (back && back[h] || 0)
                        + (back && back[j] || 0)
                        + (back && back[k] || 0)
                        + (line[h] || 0)
                        + (line[k] || 0)
                        + (next && next[h] || 0)
                        + (next && next[j] || 0)
                        + (next && next[k] || 0);

        switch (neighbors) {
        case 3:  return 1;
        case 2:  return cell;
        default: return 0;
        }
    }));
}
```

```css
pre.life {
    line-height: 0.666;
}
```

```html
<pre class="life">
                                      
                         ■            
                       ■ ■            
             ■■      ■■            ■■ 
            ■   ■    ■■            ■■ 
 ■■        ■     ■   ■■               
 ■■        ■   ■ ■■    ■ ■            
           ■     ■       ■            
            ■   ■                     
             ■■                       
                                      
                                      
                                      
                                      
                                      
                                      
                                      
                                      
                                      
                                      
                                      
                                      
                                      
                                       </pre>
```

The above pattern is the [Gosper glider gun](http://www.conwaylife.com/w/index.php?title=Gosper_glider_gun).

Comment: this is great, thanks. i like that your script inserts the game at the top of my question when run in console. ;)

Comment: If you thought my answer was helpful then do consider upvoting and accepting it.